# C# process see output in console and get a copy of it at the same time

Tags: c#, process, stdout, stderr

I'm writing an application that does analysis on other applications,
the user can choose which application he wants to analyze and run it...
a console would be opened and he'll see his application progress (output) and will be able to stop his application at anytime (by closing the console).

on my side (the application that runs the analysis), I need to get the user's application output (stdout & stderr) and run some parsing on it.

so to sum up:

(1) users' application must run in a new console window so that the user could stop the analysis at any point by closing the new console.

(2) user must be able to see his application output in the console to know when to stop it.

(3) the "parent" application will need a copy of that output (doesn't matter real time or not).

tried redirecting streams - makes (3) work but (2) not..

so how can I achieve all 3 requests above at the same time in a single run?
any ideas??

Comment: in the title!
"see output in console and get a copy of it at the same time"

is there a way to achieve all 3 options I mentioned at the same time?

Comment: Does the UI have to be an actual console window and the close button being used to stop it? Is there a reason you can't present the output through your own programs UI and provide a stop button?

Comment: Have you heard of [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? You can specify listeners to the trace, and use `Write` and `WriteLine` like `Console`

Comment: well, displaying a console is the best way to ensure that everything works correctly...
user's application could be anything! it could ask for inputs during execution... doesn't seem correct usage for my UI to simulate a console and provide a way to stream input to it

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out, if anyone is interested in the solution:

```
StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder("");
StringBuilder errStr = new StringBuilder("");

process.Start();
process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) =>
{
    outStr.AppendLine(outLine.Data);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(outLine.Data); // echo the output
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, errorLine) =>
{
    errStr.AppendLine(errorLine.Data);
    Console.Error.WriteLine(errorLine.Data); // echo the error
};

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```